# Update progress bar inside Model in WPF with .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, progress-bar

I am writing an application (in .NET 4, *not* 4.5) that performs a time consuming task, with that task being held within a Model. For example:

CalculatorModel.cs:

```
private void Execute(){
   for(int x=0; x<100; x++){
      // do task
      //then report progress
   }
}
```

My MainWindow.xaml.cs looks like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();    
}

private void buttonCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   CalculatorModel calculator = new CalculatorModel();
   calculator.Execute();      
}
```

I would rather not do all my processing within a thread in the MainWindow.xaml.cs. I read there was IProgress that could perform this task but it appears to be .NET 4.5 only.

Comment: do you expect a single task/progressbar? or there could be many such tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Do heavy (read time consuming) work in its `DoWork` event and keep updating UI about progress using event `ProgressChanged`.

For more read this [BackgroundWorker Component and MVVM](http://jeremybytes.blogspot.in/2012/05/backgroundworker-component-and-mvvm.html)

Answer (score 0):

A simple example using service class concept, assuming you just need 1 progress bar

xaml

```
<ProgressBar xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF"
             Value="{Binding CurrentProgress,Source={x:Static l:ProgressService.Instance}}" />
```

cs

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class ViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
            dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

            dt.Tick += (s, e) => ProgressService.Instance.CurrentProgress += 10;
            dt.Start();
        }
    }

    class ProgressService : DependencyObject
    {
        static ProgressService()
        {
            Instance = new ProgressService();
        }

        public static ProgressService Instance { get; private set; }

        public double CurrentProgress
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(CurrentProgressProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CurrentProgressProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentProgress.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentProgressProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentProgress", typeof(double), typeof(ProgressService), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

    }
}
```

so by manipulating the static property `ProgressService.Instance.CurrentProgress` you can report progress from any part of your code.

Answer (score -1):

All of the answers failed to address the issue so I will answer it myself for future reference:

In the MainWindow.xaml.cs::

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   progressBar.Maximum = 1000;

   bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
   bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
   Calculator calc = new Calculator();
   bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(calc.bw_DoWork);
   bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
   bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
}

// the rest of the threading methods here
```

And in CalculatorModel.cs:

```
public void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
      BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

      if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
      {
         e.Cancel = true;
      }
      else
      {
      for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
      {
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
         worker.ReportProgress(x);
      }
   }
}
```